# Delete repeated and concatenate values Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this Arrays

```
const array1 = ['546546546546', '01/01/2020', 'A']; 
const array2 = ['866465465465', '01/01/2020', 'B'];
const array3 = ['546546546546', '05/01/2020', 'B'];
```

The first value from array1 and Array3 is the same. But the rest is not the same.

I want to eliminate those that are repeated in the  value 0 and concatenate what they have in 1 and 2.

To get something like this:

```
['546546546546', '01/01/2020 A - 05/01/2020 B']; 
['866465465465', '01/01/2020 B'];
```

Comment: *"I want to eliminate those that ..."* but have you tried to do it? If yes, then post your code attempt here and then we can help you to fix the issues you may have

Comment: And you want your output to be an array of arrays? Wouldn't it be better to have an object where the keys are the `arrayX[0]` and the value is the string concatenated? Also it's not really clear what you want to do with `array3` if it has the same value as others, set it to null? Please, [edit] your question, it's not clear and it's not showing code effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary with the first element in the array as a key. I used `Array.prototype.reduce` to create a dictionary and finally extract the values out of the dictionary with `Object.values` will give your result

```js
const array1 = ['546546546546', '01/01/2020', 'A'];
const array2 = ['866465465465', '01/01/2020', 'B'];
const array3 = ['546546546546', '05/01/2020', 'B'];
// group it into a single array for looping
const input = [array1, array2, array3];

const groupedValues = input.reduce((group, [key, date, name]) => {
  // if exist concat the date and name with previous value
  if (group[key]) {
    group[key][1] = `${group[key][1]} - ${date} ${name}`;
  } else {
    // initialize if doesnt exist
    group[key] = [key, `${date} ${name}`];
  }

  return group;
}, {});

const output = Object.values(groupedValues);

console.log(output);
```